# cython with array of pointers

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a list of numpy.ndarrays (with different length) in python and need to have very fast access to those in python. I think an array of pointers would do the trick. I tried:

```
float_type_t* list_of_arrays[no_of_arrays]
for data_array in python_list_of_arrays:
    list_of_arrays[0] = data_array
```

But cython complains:

```
no_of_arrays < Not allowed in a constant expression
```

I have tried several ways to constify this variable:

```
cdef extern from *:
    ctypedef int const_int "const int"
```

(there have been more creative attempts) - however it unfortunatley doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use a numpy object array instead of a list of arrays?

I think the problem you're having is because you are declaring `list_of_arrays` in the stack, and its size must be known at compile-time. You can try some [dynamic allocation](http://wiki.cython.org/DynamicMemoryAllocation), like this:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef float_type_t *list_of_arrays = \
    <float_type_t *>malloc(no_of_arrays * sizeof(float_type_t*))

for i in range(no_of_arrays):
    list_of_arrays[i] = &(data_array[i].data)

# don't forget to free list_of_arrays!
```

(This assumes `data_array` is a numpy array.)

But this is still guessing a bit what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Tiago, it's critical for me that I don't have any python overhead when accessing each of those arrays individually. Currently they reside in a list and I often need to switch between them and that is an amazing time drain.

Comment: So I tried out the object nparray - that's the way to go. cheers