# Array of pointers in Cython

Tags: arrays, cython

I have the following `Cython` code (the syntax is based on the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983740/4189299):

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

def test_func():
    cdef int n = 10
    cdef char *array = <char *>malloc(n * sizeof(char*))
    for i in range(n):
        array[i] = NULL
    free(array)
```

It throws the compile-time error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

def test_func():
    cdef int n = 10
    cdef char *array = <char *>malloc(n * sizeof(char*))
    for i in range(n):
        array[i] = NULL
                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:7:19: Cannot assign type 'void *' to 'char'
```

For some reason an array of `char` instead of `char*` is getting generated. Therefore, can anyone help me to obtain an array of `char*` in `Cython`?

Answer (score 4):

I have figured it out. The correct syntax is:

```
cdef char **array = <char**>malloc(n * sizeof(char*))
```